# console.log return specific element

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, console.log

I have a javascript function which returns the following output:

```
[ TextCommand { _textPattern: 'ping', _handler: 'pingCommand' } ]
```

How can I directly output the text "ping" when using `console.log`?

I tried and failed with this:

```
console.log(entry._commands.TextCommand._textPattern);
```

Just for info:

```
console.log(entry._commands);
```

Will output:

```
[ TextCommand { _textPattern: 'ping', _handler: 'pingCommand' } ]
```

Do I have to parse or stringify to get a result?

Comment: try with iteration loop

Comment: Use `console.dir` to inspect the structure of your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `_commands` property is an array (not an object), so you should get the first element (0) of it to get the `_textPattern` property.

```
console.log(entry._commands[0]._textPattern);
```

Answer (score 2):

//entry._commands is an array which conatains object
console.log(entry._commands[0]._textPattern);

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
console.log(entry._commands[0]._textPattern);
```